# Proc crashes even if it allocates less memory than limited by ulimit

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, stack, ulimit

I have set stack size to 2000Kb by ulimit -s 2000 and ulimit -Ss 2000 for hard limit. And in the below program i have allocated appox 2040000(510000 x 4) bytes which is less than i limited i.e,. 2048000(2000*4)bytes but i see that my program crashes! Can anybody suggest why this happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main()
{
    int a[510000] = {0};
    a[510000] = 1;
    printf("%d", a[510000]);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(70);
}
```

EDIT 1: Crash is not because of the array index out of bound as i tried lower index and still crashes. This happens only when i limit by ulimit.

Comment: why you need `#include <malloc.h>`?

Comment: These lines `a[510000] = 1; printf("%d", a[510000]);`..........Oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int a[510000]` will be an array with index from `0` to `509999`. `a[510000]` is outside the array range.

Comment: Hi, Please check EDIT 1 in description.

Comment: @Coder Did you try to change the stack size? I guess to 4000 kbytes.

Comment: Yes, I found that with 4000kb limit it wasn't crashing and with 1000kb it is crashing every time but with 2000kb it crashes randomly. So i think something is getting added beyond want i am allocating, to prove this is there any way i can see the current stack usage by my program?

Comment: What you can do is to init your whole stack at a fixed value and look if your stack get corrupted by something.

Comment: @Coder I tried your code and I see the same thing. But if I launch it as su it always run correctly.

Comment: Ok. I try to post another example to stack overflow to see if someone has an idea. Mmmm very strange.

Comment: @Coder Take a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293068/segmentation-fault-with-ulimit-set-correctly/31293911#31293911)

Comment: Hi LPs, Using su suppresses ulimit i think plus thank you for the link, in which i have a doubt(hope i am not bothering you too much ;)), adding a break point just before main and checking the stack register(?) how do i do this? i mean how do i check the status of a register? If thats the case can i also see the current total stack usage of my application?

Comment: @Coder If you run your app with gdb you can print all register by command info registers.

Comment: i am trying to see the current stack size by setting the breakpoint in GDB, i am looking at difference of ebp and esp registers values, is that the correct way? If not please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it is. Usually ebp is set to esp at the start of function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, in below mentioned statements

```
  a[510000] = 1;
  printf("%d", a[510000]);
```

you're having *[off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)* index. The above statements are accessing array out of bounds. This  in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). One of the side effects of UB, other than [getting a nasal demon](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal+demons) is segmentation fault (The "Crash!!").

Remember, `C` uses `0`-based array indexing.

Comment: Hi, i am aware of that. so I tried this 
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[510000] = {0};
    a[51000] = 1;
    printf("%d", a[51000]);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(70);
}

and it crashes.

Note: not crashing when not limiting by ulimit!

Answer (score 0):

You're corrupting the stack in

```
a[510000] = 1;
```

because the last index in that array is one less than 510000. So that assignment overwrites data on the stack and once other statements try to use that data your application crashes.

Comment: Hi, Please check EDIT 1 in description.